# Updating JLabel with new data once every hour

Tags: java, swing

So i currently have an arraylist in Java containing:

```
{"Sam has won", "Charles has lost", "Sam has lost"}
```

And at start, my JLabel will display "Sam has won" as shown below:

```
Sam has won
```

But I want to be able to update the JLabel automatically **once every hour**, moving on with "Charles has lost". Hence, after one hour, my JLabel will update it's content to: Note that for **testing**, I'll let the **application run** and wait for one hour to see **the label updated**, since there's **no dedicated update button** which must be pushed to update, but rather letting the application run and **update on it's own** hourly.

```
Charles has lost
```

and so on.

So far I've come to know about **Timer class** and **TimerTask class**, but I'm having difficulty distinguishing them both. Could anyone demonstrate an example based on my scenario above?

Comment: Use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html), not java.util.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javax.swing.Timer. An example inspired from Fred Schwarz's [article](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/other/10time/20timer.html):

```
javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(60 * 60 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //Change your label's text
              p.repaint();
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `javax.swing.Timer` class.
You can test it like this:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private int selectedNameIndex = 0;

    public Test() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList.add("Sam has won");
        nameList.add("Charles has lost");
        nameList.add("Sam has lost");

        Timer timer = new Timer(60 * 60 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
//        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() { // for test
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(nameList.get(selectedNameIndex));
                selectedNameIndex++;
                if (selectedNameIndex >= nameList.size()) {
                    selectedNameIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
        add(label);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack(); setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```